# FastReport .NET Core (Blazor)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, fastreport

Hi guys currently I am working with the FastReport Online Designer within a Microsoft Blazor application.
Now I've got an issue and don't know how to handle it.

As soon as I create some new components (for example Textblock, Barcode ...) it won't refresh inside my C# Report class. Only when I clicked on "Save" via the interface the report is updated. But I want to refresh it manually via code.
I've read the documentation and googled a lot, but I couldn't find anything.

I hope that somebody has already work withit and can help me.

Best regards

Comment: Any chance you can get a code snippet up here on what you're trying to do? I know that calling `StateHasChanged()` is something that can refresh a Blazor component, but not sure if that's actually relevant here.

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots. See below.

Answer (score 0):

@Uxonith

Sure.

In the first image you can see my report with 3 components (1x textblock, 2x barcode). That's a report I have loaded into the designer.
Everything is fine.

In the second image you can see that these 3 objects are inside my c#-report class registered.

In the third image you can see I added one new textblock component but my c#-report class not updated yet (image 4)

And it won't update until I will save it through the FastReport Userinterface (image 5).
After I clicked on the save button the c#-report is updated and my new components are visible (see image 6).

How can I trigger this kind of refresh the save button does in the background?

Image 1 `https://i.ibb.co/hLKYPHx/fr-all-Objects-before-ui.png`

Image 2 `https://i.ibb.co/X4x1zMZ/fr-all-Objects-before.jpg`

Image 3 `https://i.ibb.co/h2SydRF/fr-all-Objects-new-Comp-before.jpg`

Image 4 `https://i.ibb.co/B2qmBMH/fr-new-Comp-after.jpg`

Image 5 `https://i.ibb.co/2dFtQ2M/fr-new-Comp-save.jpg`

Image 6 `https://i.ibb.co/J7r4kvP/fr-all-Objects-after-Save.jpg`

(Sorry I couldn't added links here, stackoverflow is broken :D )

StateHasChanged() is also called but I think this is a refresh issue from the designer.
The designer is rendered through an IFrameDesigner which comes from FastReport.Web.Blazor.Components

Comment: That adds a lot of clarity to the issue. Sadly, I'm only familiar with Blazor and not FastReport and this seems like a FastReport limitation/issue. I wish you luck!

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Thank you!